# Changing state directly after action has been dispatched

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working on a simple quiz application and want to dispatch an action (called **FreeResponseSubmit**) to store the user's input (called **searchField**) into the answers object and then reset the form field. I've tried to chain promises, and while the answers object is updated with the user's input the second "then" doesn't work as planned (I'm assuming the response from the previous promise isn't usable), and the searchField value is never reset.

Are promises even the right way to go on this or is async/await a better route? I've been racking my brain for some time trying to figure this out (still new to these frameworks) so any help is greatly appreciated.

free-response.component:

```
handleClick(){
  const searchFieldPromise= new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      resolve(this.state.searchField);
  });
  searchFieldPromise.then((searchField)=>this.props.freeResponseSubmit(searchField))
  .then((value)=>this.setState({searchField:""}));
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? `resolve(this.state.searchField)`

Comment: Is this.state.searchField what will be passed into the first then statement?

Comment: Yes, it is. But it is not an async operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic within the `handleClick` method can actually be simplified into this:

```
const { searchField } = this.state;
const { freeResponseSubmit } = this.props;
freeResponseSubmit(searchField);
this.setState({
  searchField:''
});
```

This is because the action for `freeResponseSubmit` would have already taken in the value from your component's state, thus carrying out any subsequent operations within redux. Therefore, you can just clear the component's state.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the action is called directly with the value or could be delayed a bit, although now that I say it that doesn't seem likely at all. Thank you for your help!